# Amazon Logstash Usage

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is the use of Logstash, and how can I use in my project of containing the dynamodb database. Without using Lambda, we can use Logstash. Was the Logstash work as Lambda or in different process. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

*Logstash is an open source, server-side data processing pipeline that ingests data from a multitude of sources simultaneously, transforms it, and then sends it to your favorite “stash.” (Ours is Elasticsearch, naturally.)*.
[Link](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)

You can use logstash to collect your data logs, process, and send it to a server for centralized and view it with a tool like [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)